# Unable to launch abstract method

Tags: java

I have a abstract class named Animal with an abstract method named move. Also, a Fish class that extends the Animal class and defines a method named move. When I try to test the method in a class named test the method does not seem to launch. I was expecting that after compiling all the files and executing the test file it would print "fish is swimming" but nothing is printed and no errors shown.

/// Animal class

```
public abstract class Animal {

    int age;
    String gender;
    int weightInLbs;

    public Animal(int age, String gender, int weightInLbs) {
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.weightInLbs = weightInLbs;
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating...");
    }

    public void sleep() {
        System.out.println("Sleeping...");
    }

    public abstract void move();
}
```

// Fish class

```
public class Fish extends Animal {

    public Fish (int age, String gender, int weightInLbs) {
        super(age, gender, weightInLbs);
    }

    public void swim() {
        System.out.println("Swimming...");
    }

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("fish is swimming...");
    }
}
```

// test class

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Fish fish1 = new Fish(1, "M", 3);
        fish1.move();
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything seems ok to me... Are you sure it isn't printing anything?

Comment: It's printing "fish is swimming..." for me. Try to clean and rebuild.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the program?

Comment: How do you launch the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It its a launch problem, your code is correct and works perfecly.

> For a better legibility add @Override to the methods that you are
>   overriding.

Just follow the next steps to test it:

1. Open Eclipse or any IDK tool that you use and create a new Project (i.e: Java Project).
2. Create the three clases (Animal, Fish and test (**Test**)).
3. Paste your code into each of them.
4. Right click on test -> Run as -> Java Aplication.
5. Open the console: Windows -> Show View -> Console

You will now see "fish is swimming".
Good Luck.